# Dependency service and mediaPlayer

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am using dependency service to use Android MediaPlayer, however once i return the value from media player to shared project the value mediaplayer is null. I have seen and tried https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/MediaElementDemos/MediaElementDemos.Android/VideoPicker.cs

My interface

```
public interface IDictionaryPlayer
   {
        MediaPlayer SetGong(int timeoutBetweenWords);
  
   }
```

Droid

```
  public MediaPlayer SetGong(int timeout)
     {
                MediaPlayer pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.gong);
    
                return pausesPlayer;
                
    }
```

Shared project

```
    public static MediaPlayer GongPlayer;
    
         public static void SetPauseOrGongBetweenWords(int timeoutBetweenWords)
         {
                            GongPlayer = DependencyService.Get<IDictionaryPlayer>().SetGong(timeoutBetweenWords); // HERE ITS NULL
                            initialize = true;
       GongPlayer.Start();
         }

 public static void TryPausePlayer()
        {
            lock (playerLock)
            {
               
                if (GongPlayer != null && GongPlayer.IsPlaying)
                {
                    gongNeedsResume = true;
                    GongPlayer?.Pause();
                }
            }
        }
  public static void TryResumePlayer()
        {
           if (gongNeedsResume)
            {
                    gongNeedsResume = false;
                    GongPlayer?.Start();
            }
            
        }

 internal static void Clean()
        {
            disposeActive = true;

            if (GongPlayer != null)
            {
                GongPlayer.Dispose();
                GongPlayer = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: MediaPlayer is an Android specific type and your shared code does not know how to reference it

Comment: And how can i reference it?

Comment: I have tried to use activity but i cant seem to find the right method

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the MediaElement?  If you have to go this route, you need to expose the methods you need to access via your Interface and all of the actual work happens in the platform class

Comment: @Jason I have updated my question, maybe that will help

Comment: all of those methods need to be encapsulated in the Android code and exposed via the Interface

Comment: Thank you, So should i have the initialization of the MediaPlayer in my Shared or Droid project?

Comment: EVERYTHING involving the MediaPlayer should go in the Droid project because MedaPlayer is a Droid native object.  Your Forms project only interacts with it via the operations you define in the Interface.

Comment: alright , thank you

Comment: @nananoDe Hi, if problem has been solved, remember to share the solution in answer when you have time. It will be helpful for others to know how to solve that.